# How to use filters in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I have this collection :

```
  { id: 1, courseId: 2, text: 'John' },
  { id: 2, courseId: 2, text: 'Willi' },
  { id: 3, courseId: 2, text: 'Inga' },
  { id: 4, courseId: 1, text: 'Jerry' },
  { id: 5, courseId: 1, text: 'Michael' },
  { id: 1, courseId: 3, text: 'John' },
  { id: 2, courseId: 3, text: 'Willi' },
  { id: 3, courseId: 4, text: 'Inga' },
  { id: 4, courseId: 5, text: 'Jerry' },
  { id: 5, courseId: 5, text: 'Michael' }
```

I want to render in view  with help of ng-repeat directive only records that have id =1 and id=2 and id=5.

How can I do it using filter in angularjs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom filter that will do the trick

**Markup**

```
ng-repeat="item in items | filterArray: [1, 2, 5]"
```

**Filter**

```
app.filter('filterArray', function() {
  return function(inputArray, arrayToCompare) {
    return inputArray.filter(function(value) {
      console.log(arrayToCompare.indexOf(value.id), value)
      return arrayToCompare.indexOf(value.id) != -1;
    })
  }
})
```

[**Working PLunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/LqmCJEgq4SO5KpDahvV5?p=preview)